# Magento-2 Custom product price not working for multi-shipping checkout

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php

Custom product price not working for multi shipping checkout.

Here is my code for the custom product price

app\code\Custom\Module\etc\frontend\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
 <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
     <observer name="customprice" instance="Custom\Module\Observer\Customprice" />
 </event>
</config>
```

app\code\Custom\Module\Observer\Customprice.php

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class Customprice implements ObserverInterface
{
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
     $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
     $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
     $price = 100; //set your price here
     $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
 }

}
```

Comment: have you get any solution for this  issue @Lokesh M

Comment: @divyasekar can you please upload screenshot?

Comment: can you try to move your events.xml to etc folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prices of the items are set in the following functionality:

```
\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Subtotal
```

Inside the `_initItem()` function you can find the logic that obtains the final price for configurable or simple products, in this logic the`$this->_calculateRowTotal($item, $finalPrice, $originalPrice)` function is called which sets the Item price.

You can use a `<preference />` and override the logic of one of those methods (`_initItem()` or `_calculateRowTotal`) to apply your custom price, for example:

MODULE_DIR/etc/frontend/di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Subtotal" type="Vendor\YourModule\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Subtotal"/>
</config>
```

Create your custom class

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\YourModule\Model\Quote\Address\Total;

class Subtotal extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Subtotal
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function _calculateRowTotal($item, $finalPrice, $originalPrice)
    {
        // apply your logic to get the custom prices
        $finalPrice = 10; // your final custom price
        $originalPrice = 10; // your original custom price
        $item->setPrice($finalPrice)->setBaseOriginalPrice($originalPrice);
        $item->calcRowTotal();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me check and update you

Comment: I was get the custom price. Where going to set my custom price in the above function

Comment: When i click a checkout with multiple address I get  the custom price value as null

Comment: @divyasekar You have to change the `$finalPrice` and `$originalPrice` values using your custom logic.